# Is Dean's name in Supernatural a reference to Gilmore Girls?

Tags: names, supernatural, behind-the-scenes, actors

Jared Padalecki portrayed **Dean** in *Gilmore Girls* and then, in *Supernatural*, his chararacter Sam had a brother named **Dean**.

[image]
[image]

Jared Padalecki's roles in *Gilmore Girls* and *Supernatural* are among his most well known:

> [He] rose to fame in the early 2000s after appearing [as Dean Forester] on the television series *Gilmore Girls* [...]. Padalecki is best known for his role as Sam Winchester on *Supernatural*.
>
> <sub>from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jared_Padalecki)</sub>

Has anyone involved in making *Supernatural* ever mentioned whether Sam's brother being named Dean was a reference to *Gilmore Girls*?

Answer (score 10):

### No.

Eric Kripke, the creator and original showrunner of *Supernatural*, named Dean (and more indirectly Sam) as a homage to Jack Kerouac's road-trip novel *On the Road*.

From an [article on DailyTelegraph](http://www.dailytelegraph.com.au/entertainment/fact-scarier-than-fiction/story-e6frexlr-1111113119827):

> At the heart of the show are brothers Sam and Dean Winchester (Jared Padalecki and Jensen Ackles). When they were young their mother was killed by a demon. Now they're on a quest to hunt down such ghouls.
>
> The brothers were named after the characters Sal and Dean, from the classic beat novel On The Road, by Jack Kerouac. Kripke didn't like the idea of having a lead named Sal, so he switched to Sam.